# Maven WebApplication jar launches error

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml

I am trying to create executable Maven project with Tomcat included. I use Spring Tool Suite.

when I launch it from the CMD (Windows) I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Home\.extract\webapps\test.war (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:113)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:843)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:387)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apr 15, 2017 11:21:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid or unreadable WAR file : C:\Users\Home\.extract\webapps\test.war
        at org.apache.naming.resources.WARDirContext.setDocBase(WARDirContext.java:133)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4906)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5086)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apr 15, 2017 11:21:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Apr 15, 2017 11:21:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Apr 15, 2017 11:21:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/test] startup failed due to previous errors
Apr 15, 2017 11:21:00 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-36001"]
```

My pom.xml file contains following lines:

```
     <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <tomcat7Version>7.0.33</tomcat7Version>
</properties>

  <build>
    <finalName>Guard</finalName>
            <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>tomcat-run</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <server>localhost</server>
                        <path>/test</path>
                        <enableNaming>false</enableNaming>
                        <finalName>guard_server.jar</finalName>
                        <charset>utf-8</charset>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                  <version>${tomcat7Version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
                  <version>${tomcat7Version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
                  <version>${tomcat7Version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tomcat-api</artifactId>
                  <version>${tomcat7Version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                  <version>${tomcat7Version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
                  <version>${tomcat7Version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
                  <version>${tomcat7Version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
                  <version>${tomcat7Version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
                  <version>${tomcat7Version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
                  <version>${tomcat7Version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tomcat-el-api</artifactId>
                  <version>${tomcat7Version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
                  <version>${tomcat7Version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tomcat-tribes</artifactId>
                  <version>${tomcat7Version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tomcat-catalina-ha</artifactId>
                  <version>${tomcat7Version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
                  <version>${tomcat7Version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

        </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Any ideas how to resolve it?

Note: on macOs using also STS I don't have any problem in compiling and launching the same project

Comment: in your `pom.xml` change ` <path>/test</path>` to ` <path>\test</path>` and try again.

Comment: No effect :( the same exception...

Comment: Actually I would even prefer to use just / to obtain address : localhost:8080/ instead of localhost:8080/test